# Snomed codes vs ICD Codes

Tags: health-informatics, icd-intrntl-classif-disea

I know ICD 10 codes are used to describe Granular Level diagnosis on a patient.

Do SNOMED codes do the same?  If Yes, why two set of terminologies to describe diagnosis?

Is it because SNOMed Codes are more Provider Friendly while ICD 10 codes are more billing friendly?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? How do you assert that "friendliness" (of your acronyms). Please help us to help you. You may improve your question to comply better with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ICD-10 is a classification system which can be used to record certain disease states of a patient, e.g. `I50` meaning "Heart failure" or `I50.1` meaning "Left ventricular failure".

SNOMED CT provides multiple advantages:

1. SNOMED CT covers all clinical terms, not just disease states.  For example we can say `85232009` meaning "left heart failure" but we could also say `163053002` meaning "raised JVP", `162965007` meaning "lung crackles heard", `421346005` meaning "3+ pitting oedema".

Alternatively, we could say `315261000000101` meaning "patient advised to attend emergency department", `239471000000109` meaning "emergency ambulance call" and `1079771000000108` meaning "transported by ambulance".

2. SNOMED CT has a grammar, allowing the creation of "expressions".  For example, we can say:

`236721000000106` meaning "Implantation of intravenous dual chamber cardiac pacemaker system (procedure)"

`236721000000106:363704007=91470000` meaning "Implantation of intravenous dual chamber cardiac pacemaker system (procedure) into the axilla"

`236721000000106:363704007=91470000, 272741003 = 7771000` meaning "Implantation of intravenous dual chamber cardiac pacemaker system (procedure) into the axilla, left side"

3. SNOMED CT is far more granular than ICD-10.  There are many more specific codes.  Furthermore, SNOMED CT expressions as above allow almost any clinical concept to be described in detail.

I would strongly recommend this guide for learning more about SNOMED CT (https://confluence.ihtsdotools.org/display/DOCSTART/SNOMED+CT+Starter+Guide)

Comment: Thanks JWC. Is it correct to assume that not every Snomed Code has a corresponding ICD 10 code but every ICD 10 code has a corresponding Snomed Code.  The reason being that some SNOMED codes also represent doctor care instructions for a patient?

Comment: Hi, yes - that's broadly correct but SNOMED includes much more than just doctor care instructions - that was simply an example I used to illustrate. There are codes for professions, procedures, advice, medications, family relationships, socioeconomic status, genetics, medical devices (and non-medical devices!). It is a huge collection of terms which allow for almost any statement about clinical care to be made. There are also dedicated mappings for linking ICD10 and SNOMED terms in a reproducible manner.

Comment: Thank you JWC.  I will review the confluence link you sent above to gain further understanding of the SNOMed codes.

Answer (score -2):

There are two sets of terminologies because their different purpose. It also sometimes useful to have a competition of two terminologies.

(btw - we also have 2 app stores that serve the same purpose. We really need just one. But we have two for some good reasons)

Comment: Answers without supporting references will be deleted. Also, just saying they serve different purposes isn't really an answer.